# How to Include non-matching id in JPA OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have a table with a column that has non-foreign key (no actual table reference) reference on another table but the other table might not have a matching row

```java
class Component {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PART_ID", referencedColumnName="PART_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Part part
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPONENT_ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

Part class

```java
class Part {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PART_ID")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

without this `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` I am getting an error
but with this I am not getting an error and get null value but I need the `id` to be present

e.g) I am looking for this

```
{"component": {"id":12, "part":{"id":100,"name":null}}}
```

but I am getting this (if no match)

```
{"component": {"id":12, "part":null}}
```

but I am getting this (if match)

```
{"component": {"id":12, "part":{"id":100,"name":"part_name"}}}
```

Tried with `nullable=false` and some combinations for `updatable` and `insertable` and still nothing works

Answer (score 0):

If table has reference on another table but the other table might not have a matching row , the database structure is probably broken.
Do you really need what you're asking for?

The database has 2 part_id. One in Component and the other in Part. Java code has only one - Part.

You can make an additional field

```
сlass Component {
    private Long partId;
...
```

and  in the @PostLoad method - create a new Part with the desired id.

```
@PostLoad
public void postLoad(){
  if(part == null && partId!=null){
    part= new Part();
    part.setId(partId)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: you are right there is no table reference foreign key but need to combine them in hibernate, is there a way?